# WordPress Multisite - get_plugin_data()

Tags: plugins, multisite, get-plugin-data

I use WordPress Multisite. I have multiple sites with plugins installed. I can successfully get a list of the plugin paths with the option value `active_plugins` from each site.

I can not get additional data from `get_plugin data`.

**I use this code:**

```
$plugins = get_blog_option($blog_id, 'active_plugins');
foreach( $plugins as $plugin )
{
    var_dump( get_plugin_data($plugin) );
}
```

**The error message:**

"*Warning: fopen(akismet/akismet.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\blogs\multisite\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3493*"

If this is not working on a multisite environment, is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the value inside the var `$plugin`. The function `get_plugin_data` will use the completed path, like `/var/www/wp/wp-content/plugins/akismet/akismet.php`.

Add the path before your plugin-folder and it works. I think you can use the constant `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`.